# android facebook logout issues

Tags: android, facebook

I have implemeted code for facebook connection to post message on wall , refere from this  link https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk ... every thing is working fine...

Now my issues is when I do logout() it is showing me logout successfully ...

```
        private void clearCredentials() {
    try {
        facebookConnector.getFacebook().logout(getApplicationContext());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        }
```

but when next time open an app ... it is not logged out....
  Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

add this method in your facebook sdk `facebook.java` class and use your activity

```
   public String logout(Context context)
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    Util.clearCookies(context);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("method", "auth.expireSession");
    String response = request(b);
    setAccessToken(null);
    setAccessExpires(0);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply , but this is already done in facebook.java class...
Still facing problem in logout...